# How to inject a dinamically created element into an existing div in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a list of objects `photos`, from a json data file, that I would like to organize into 3 different `<div>` columns, but I dont know how to achieve that, here is my broken non-optimized code:

```js
<div className="container">
    <div ref={leftColRef} className="left-col" />
    <div ref={centreColRef} className="centre-col" />
    <div ref={rightColRef} className="right-col" />
    {Object.keys(photos).forEach((n, i) => {
        const id = photos[n].id;
        const thumb = photos[n].thumbnailUrl;
        const title = photos[n].title;
        const element = (
            <Thumbnail id={id} title={title} thumb={thumb} />
        );
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            leftColRef.current.append(element);
        } else if (i % 3 === 1) {
            centreColRef.current.append(element);
        } else {
            rightColRef.current.append(element);
        }
        // this line works, it idsplays the data but is commented as the data needs to go inside its respective columns
        // return <Thumbnail key={id} title={title} thumb={thumb} />;
    })}
</div>
```

The idea is to insert some elements into the left-column when `i%3 = 0` and others in the centre-column when `i%3 = 1` and so on ...

And a link to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-fetch-data-example-r0cf5)

Any help/advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is probably to prepare the data outside the render function and to render the column one by one.

You should not manipulate the DOM like it's done in jQuery using JSX

Example:

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const filterPhotos = (column) => {
        return props.photos.filter((photo,index)=> index%3==column);
    }

    return <>
        <MyColumn photos={filterPhotos(0)}/>
        <MyColumn photos={filterPhotos(1)}/>
        <MyColumn photos={filterPhotos(2)}/>
    </>;
}
```

Comment: I added an example in my anwser

Answer (score 2):

First, using ref on div to inject stuff on it is wrong. It's the opposite of how react works.

Like charlies said, I would split the photos in 3 different arrays before the render. Then, you'll be able to do something like this :

`<div ref={leftColRef} className="left-col" />
    { photosLeft.map(photo => <Thumbnail key={photo.id} {...photo} />)
</div>`

when preparing your data, try to use the same object properties and component props name so you can spread it easily ( **{...photo}** ).

Note: Also, when rendering an array in react, each child must have a unique key props. It will help react to render on that part of dom if your data change.